# Is there an equivalent of addr2line on AIX system?

Tags: compiling, aix, debugging, xlc

I'd like to debug proftpd on AIX and according to the documentation, `addr2line` is a usefull binary to identify what is not working.

*Extract of proftpd debugging documentation:*

```
 The key here for tracking down the location of the segfault is that [0] 
 frame, and the memory address: 0x809b1e1. 
 Using that address and a very handy command called addr2line, you can determine the location of that address in the source code:
  addrline -e ./proftpd 0x809b1e1
In this example, I saw:    
  golem/tj>addr2line -e ./proftpd 0x809b1e1
  /home/tj/proftpd/cvs/proftpd/modules/mod_auth.c:1723
which is the location of test code added to trigger the segfault.
```

But I can't find it on AIX, does an equivalent exist ?
and if yes what it is ?

**Edit 1**
I find `dbx` which is the AIX debugger, the man says this:

```
dbx [-a ProcessID] [-c CommandFile] [-d NestingDepth] [-I Directory]
[-p [OldPath=NewPath:... | File]] [-v] [-k] [-u] [-x] [-F] [-L] [-r]
[-C CoreFile | ObjectFile [CoreFile]]

    -a ProcessID        Attach to specified process
    -c CommandFile      Run dbx subcommands in specified file first
    -d NestingDepth     Set limit for nesting of program blocks
    -I Directory        Include Directory in list of directories
                        searched for source files
    -p OldPath=NewPath  Substitute library path for core examination
       File             Read library path substitutions for core
                        examination from File
    -C CoreFile         Allow to analyze core dump without ObjectFile
    -v                  Relax core file validity checking
    -k                  Map memory addresses
    -u                  Prepend file name symbols with an '@'
    -x                  Strip postfix '_' from FORTRAN symbols
    -F                  Read all symbols at start-up time
    -L                  Keep linkage symbols
    -r                  Run object file immediately
```

Does this program can help me ?
and how (I'm very not comfortable with `C` compilation and debugging without an IDE )

Comment: In `gdb proftpd`, you should be able to do `list *0x809b1e1`. `gdb` is available for a number of operating systems, but so are the GNU binutils (where addr2line comes from). Have you tried installing the GNU binutils on AIX?

Comment: I'm not admin and I can't request additional software. what's `gdb` ?

Comment: `gdb` is the GNU debugger. You don't need super-user privilege to install software in your home directory (or any directory you have write access to). If you can't use `gdb`, you may be able to do the same with whatever AIX provides as a debugger.